# How do I send email to Client and Admin through my IONIC2 app?

Tags: email, ionic2

I am developing an ionic2 app in which i have to send email to admin and client after successful payment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

This is quite easy with ionic, follow the below steps for sending email.
First install this `plugin`:

```
$ ionic plugin add --save cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/social-sharing
```

After this in your view/page from where you want to send email:
import the above plugin:

```
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing';
```

Now make its object in constructor: like this

```
constructor(public socialSharing:SocialSharing) {
   }
```

Now finally use it to send email to anybody:

```
 this.socialSharing.canShareViaEmail().then(() => {
        this.socialSharing.shareViaEmail('Hi , ... your message', 'Subject', ['user@user.com']).then(() => {
        }).catch(() => {
            alert("Uh!! Seems like some issues right now, please try later");
            });
        })
```

Thats it !!
feel free to comment if any other issue occurs.

Comment: I am getting this error :   Typescript Error
Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.                                           
.../ionic2-firebaseauth-master/node_modules/@ionic-native/social-sharing/index.d.ts
 */
export declare class SocialSharing extends IonicNativePlugin {
    /**